Copy database during installation only in MAUI
I'd like to deploy a Sqlite database along my MAUI application. The database is ~120MB in size, so I'd like to keep only one copy of it. Ideally, it would be put somewhere where the app as read/write access during installation. How can I do this?
I only found examples where it was inside the Resources/Raw folder and I would copy it on app start (check if it's not already there). But this means double the memory consumption, which seems kind of stupid.

the only want to do this would be to download it from a remote site on startup.  Including it in the app package will always require duplication unless it is going to be a read-only DB

@Jason that's a good answer

If the schema is "small" then, deploy the schema in Raw or as a string resource and build the SQLite database on first run from the schema.

@StephenQuan and what about the 120MB of data?

Even with a large database binary, the schema might be compact. It's your call whether this approach suits you. Shipping a SQL schema instead of a database is often more future-proof, as it’s easier to track and update.
